# Double integral $\int\int_A y dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Calculate Double integral $$\iint_A y dxdy$$ 
where:
$$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2\le4, y \ge 0 \}$$
I do not know what would be the limit of integration if i change this to polar coordinates. I will manage to do the latter part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap the order of integration:

$$\int_{-2}^2\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}y\,dy\right)\,dx$$

But $\int_{0}^{z}y\,dy = \frac{z^2}{2}$, so the above is:

$$\int_{-2}^2 \frac{4-x^2}{2}\,dx$$

Which is easy to do.

Without swapping:

$$\int_{0}^2\left(\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}y\,dx\right)\,dy$$

With the inner integral equal to $2y\sqrt{4-y^2}$.  We can compute $$\int_0^2 2y\sqrt{4-y^2}\,dy$$ by substituting $u=y^2.$

Answer (score 3):

In polar coordinates, $r$ is going from $0$ to $2$ and $\theta$ is going from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: but could you explain why?

Comment: Since $A$ is actually upper half of an disk. Or you can just let $x=rcos \theta$ and $y=rsin \theta$